# How to get Postgres 10.x to not drop articles and pronouns from text searches

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm working on a search interface for our application, and noticed that Postgres is dropping articles and pronouns from search terms:

```
> select to_tsvector('english', 'welcome to your house')
< 'hous':4 'welcom':1
```

This creates a problem if there's something titled "Yours and Hers":

```
> select to_tsvector('english', 'yours and hers')
< (blank)
```

How do I configure text search to stop dropping articles and pronouns? I'd still like to get the benefits of searching for "jumped" and having it match "jumping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to keep stemming, but get rid of stop words.  You could alter the english dictionary in place, but this is usually a bad idea as it would present an upgrade hazard.  (Your changes would be lost after a dump and restore, or run of pg_upgrade) and it would be confusing to people not aware of the change.  So instead, you can make a copy without the stopwords.

```
create text search dictionary english_stem_nostop ( template = snowball, language = english );
create text search configuration english_nostop ( copy = english);
alter text search configuration english_nostop alter mapping replace english_stem with english_stem_nostop;

select to_tsvector('english_nostop', 'welcome to your house');
            to_tsvector             
-------------------------------------
'hous':4 'to':2 'welcom':1 'your':3
```